# How to insert array subscript in a parenscript expression?

Tags: javascript, common-lisp, parenscript

I have this code working in javascript:

```js
(document.querySelectorAll('[rel="next"]'))[0].click()
```

I am trying to write the same thing in [parenscript](https://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/) (a library from the Common Lisp ecossystem). The expressions in my current sketches are being evalued by the REPL under a package called Nyxt availabe [here](https://github.com/atlas-engineer/nyxt).

```
CL-USER> (in-package :nyxt)
```

Nyxt is designed to be an infinitely extensible browser. Thus, the user can change the code and/or create extensions while the program is running. This is live hackability by design.

Here is the code:

```lisp
(ps:chain document (query-selector-all "[rel=next]")) (click))
```

Using `ps:ps` I can "see" what parenscript is building:

```lisp
NYXT> (ps:ps (ps:chain document (query-selector-all "[rel=next]") (click)))
"document.querySelectorAll('[rel=next]').click();"
```

The above result is close to what I need. However, there is still one thing missing: the subscription of the parenscript array (id. est., "[0]" in Javascript), before the `.click()`.

I have some **failed** **attempts**.

1. If I try:

```
NYXT> (ps:ps (ps:chain document (query-selector-all "[rel=next]") [0] (click)))
```

I get an extra ".":

```
"document.querySelectorAll('[rel=next]').[0].click();"
```

2. If I try:

```
NYXT> (ps:ps (ps:chain document (query-selector-all "[rel=next]") ([0]) (click)))
```

I get an extra "." and unnecessary "()":

```
"document.querySelectorAll('[rel=next]').[0]().click();"
```

3. If I try:

```
NYXT> (ps:ps (ps:chain document (query-selector-all "[rel=next]")[0] (click)))
```

I get an extra ".":

```
"document.querySelectorAll('[rel=next]').[0].click();"
```

4. If I try:

```
NYXT> (ps:ps (ps:chain document (query-selector-all "[rel=next]" [0]) (click)))
```

I get an extra `[0]` as another argument:

```
"document.querySelectorAll('[rel=next]', [0]).click();"
```

How do I insert it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accidentaly, I discovered the answer, the trick was just to pass just `0` without `[]`:

```lisp
NYXT> (ps:ps (ps:chain document  (query-selector-all "[rel=next]") 0 (click)))

"document.querySelectorAll('[rel=next]')[0].click();"
```

I think parenscript could have more tutorials and documentation. I have struggled with it. Thus, I am leaving this here to help other Common Lisp newbies like me :)